# Showing error in Search Command Power Apps

Tags: search, powerapps

> SortByColumns(Search('[dbo].[Efftronics Systems Pvt Ltd_,$Sales Header]', TextSearchBox1.Text, "Applies-to_x0020_Doc__x0020_No_","Applies-to_x0020_ID","Area"), "Applies-to_x0020_Doc__x0020_No_", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))

[image: These are the columns in the table]

I am connect to SQLServer from powerApps. Then I have connected to one table. Then PowerAPPS Building App itself.

In the first page It is for Searching. But It is showing Error.

> Inner Exception: Syntax Error at position 8 in Applies-to_x0020_Doc__x0020_No desc

I am very new to PowerApps.

I Want to search only with No_ column values. How to write search command for this.

I am new to PowerApps. This is my first App.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put sort order after every column, you got this error because after `"Applies-to_x0020_Doc__x0020_No_"` you got `"Applies-to_x0020_ID"` instead of `If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending)`

**SortByColumns**( Table, ColumnName1 *[, SortOrder1, ColumnName2, SortOrder2, ... ]* )